# What do we mean by curves being tangent to each other on manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a $n$ dimensional smooth manifold, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be two smooth curves on $M$ with $\phi_{1\text{or} 2}:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ and $\phi_{1 or 2}(t=0)=p\in M$. I read in a set of lecture notes that by $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ being tangent at point $p$, we meant to say that we can find a local chart $(U,f)$ with $p\in U$ such that$$\frac{\partial(f\circ\phi_1)(t)}{\partial t}|_{t=0}=\frac{\partial(f\circ\phi_2)(t)}{\partial t}|_{t=0}$$
which could be proved to be chart-independent. My question is why do we require **equality** here. Could we not have one being a multiple of another and still have these curves being tangent to each other?

Comment: Probably because you are going to use this to define what a vector is, and not what a tangent line is.

Comment: Wouldn't this be inconsistent with our usual definition of tangency for curves on Euclidean space though?

Comment: There is absolutely no requirement to use the same words with the same meanings in every single context. Definitions are shortcuts to say things that we need to say to do what we want — nothing sacred about them. If you prefer, replace everywhere in that text "tangent" by "best friends". Nothing should change.

Comment: And yes, "best friends" has, in another context, a different meaning ;-)

Comment: To expand on Mariano's first comment, _tangent_ for parametric paths means _same position and velocity_. This is fully consistent with tangency of graphs in one-variable calculus: The graph $y = f(x)$ is parametrized by $(t, f(t))$, whose velocity is $(1, f'(t))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you understand the word "tangent" in the geometrical sense. In geometry the tangent to a plane curve at a point $p$ on the curve is the straight line that "just touches" the curve at $p$. This may be a bit imprecise, but it explains the intuition.

However, the concept of *tangent* in analysis differs from that in geometry. In geometry a curve in $\mathbb R^n$ is a certain subset $C \subset \mathbb R^n$, in analysis it is a function $c : J \to \mathbb R^n$ defined on an interval $J \subset \mathbb R$. In other words, one considers *parameterized curves*, and usually one even assumes that $c$ is differentiable. Roughly we can say that a geometric curve is the image $C(J)$ of an analytic curve. The concept of speed does not make any sense for geometric curves, this is tied to specific parameterizations. Even the concept of direction has to be interpreted differently; in geometry we can a best say that a direction is an equivalence class of straight lines (lines being equivalent iff they are parallel).

In analysis the tangent to a curve $c$ at $\tau \in J$ is the *parameterized straight line* $l(t) = tv + a$ with $v, a \in \mathbb R^n$ which is the best approximation to $c$ at $\tau$ in the sense that the relative deviation $\dfrac{\lvert l(t) - c(t) \rvert}{\lvert t \rvert} \to 0$ as $t \to 0$. Clearly this can be only be possible if $l(\tau) = c(\tau)$ which means that $l(t)$ must have the form $l(t) = (t -\tau)w + c(\tau)$ with $w \in \mathbb R^n$.

It is well-known that the *existence* of such $l(t)$ is equivalent to the differentiability of $c$ at $\tau$. In that case $w = c'(\tau)$.

Differentiable curves $c_i :  (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \mathbb R^n$ being tangent at $0$ means that the have the same tangent at $0$, i.e, $c'_1(0) = c'_2(0)$.